# Should I correct a successfully completed Master's dissertation before publishing online?

Tags: publications, thesis, masters, proofreading

I  successfully completed my Master's dissertation a while back and I've decided I would like to publish it online to help others and  probably print a copy for myself to up on the bookshelf. 
The dissertation was good but it wasn't perfect. Other than the usual typos, there were a few minor mistakes with how I presented the data which my professor pointed out. Should I correct these things before publishing or is that not the done thing?

Comment: Is that the first version of the thesis that is online? That is, "I've decided I would like to publish it online to help others" makes me wonder whether your university library has already published the thesis online; some universities do that.

Comment: Sure, correct them; just make sure to point out that the version you are posting is the corrected one and not the thesis-as-you-have-submitted-it. Potentially you need to remove some statements from it that claim the opposite, or some university logos that might be misconstrued as signs of an official university publication.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Comment: Thanks everyone! @mapper The dissertation is finished and I was awarded the MA. So it is the version I handed in. As for whether the university published it online for me, I don't know, It never occurred to me that that might happen

Comment: At least here in Chile the copyright on theses belongs to the university, not the author. You'd have to check the legal situation. I doubt they'd forbid you to publish it, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You should always correct and polish your work before publishing it. Therefore I would suggest you implement the fixes recommended by your professor, and correct the typos you mentioned. Having done this, you should point out somewhere in the publication that this work was partially adapted from the document you submitted to your institution, stating that you fixed a couple minor things.

[As @darijgrinberg suggests here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51277/should-i-correct-a-successfully-completed-masters-dissertation-before-publishin#comment118360_51277), you should also remove any official logos and statements that might be included in the document, as to avoid it being confused with an official university publication, let alone copyright breaches.

Comment: I disagree: I don't think he should implement the typos. ;)

Comment: @tomasz Ach. Saw it now. :)